# Why is $\int_{-1}^1 2 - |x| = 3$ rather than $-3$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is $\int_{-1}^1 2 - |x| = 3$ rather than $-3$?

I've got -3, [wolframAlpha 3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20-1%20to%201%20%282-%7Cx%7C%29).

my solution:

$f(x) = 2 - |x|, f(x) \text{ is even function}$.

$$\int_{-1}^1f(x) = 2 \int_0^1 f(x) = 2 \int_0^1 2 - x = 2\bigg(\bigg|_0^12x-\frac{x^2}{2}  \bigg) = 2\bigg(0 - (2 - \frac{1}{2}) \bigg) = 2(-1.5) = -3.$$

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You plugged the limits of integration in in the wrong order.

Comment: @DavidMitra What do you mean?

Comment: $2( (2-1/2)-0)$, not $2(0-(2-1/2))$.

Comment: $2-|x|>0$ if $x$ is between $-1$ and $1$. The integral *must* be positive

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, after you said that I remembered that the order is  F(b) - F(a) and not F(a) - F(b). Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have simply

$$f(x)\Big|_a^b=f(b)-f(a)$$

Comment: Nice to see you Sami. :)

Answer (score 1):

Beside to @David Mitra's post not that $f(x)=2-|x|$ is an even function over $I=[-1,1]$ and so you can simply use this fact that $$\int_If(x)dx=2\int_0^1(2-x)dx$$